# doOnError and onErrorResume how to combine into one operator

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have `RestController`, which returns `Mono`. And if i catch `TimeoutException`, I need log to it and return my custom `ErrorResponse`. Now, it works and looks like this:

```java
return service.someMethod(phone, ctx)
                .doOnNext(resp -> log("done")
                .timeout(timeout)
                .doOnError(TimeoutException.class, e -> log.error(ServiceErrors.CLIENT_SEARCH_TIMEOUT_ERROR + e.getLocalizedMessage()))
                .onErrorResume(TimeoutException.class, e -> Mono.just(new MyCustomWrapper<>(
                        new MyCustomError("EIPbXsxiuA" , ServiceErrors.CLIENT_SEARCH_TIMEOUT_ERROR))
                );
```

I want to combine doOnError and onErrorResume. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about removing `doOnError` and put the logging inside `onErrorResume` like this:

```java
return service.someMethod(phone, ctx)
                .doOnNext(resp -> log("done")
                .timeout(timeout)
                .onErrorResume(TimeoutException.class, e -> {
  log.error(ServiceErrors.CLIENT_SEARCH_TIMEOUT_ERROR + e.getLocalizedMessage())
  Mono.just(new MyCustomWrapper<>(
                        new MyCustomError("EIPbXsxiuA" , ServiceErrors.CLIENT_SEARCH_TIMEOUT_ERROR))
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I got a syntax error. Now I realized that I just forgot to return before Mono.just...